# How to find available memory on Google App Engine Flex Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

I've done tests with different instance class options and checked the available memory of the instance with the free -h command via SSH, the available memory doesn't change, it gives me the same 988Mi available for all instance_class settings.

It's a rails project.

Configuration file:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rails server -p 8080
env: flex
runtime: ruby
instance_class: B4_1G
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Is the instance_class setting deprecated?
Is there a way to define resources for a flex env?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `instance_class` hasn't been deprecated and is still used to specify the instance's class, which limits CPU and memory. May I know how did you configure the instances in order to be able to ssh in them? And how are you accessing them?

Notice that I would've commented but since I have too low reputation in ServerFault I'm unable to do so. Once I know the solution or root cause of the problem I will update this answer.